# do-while loop starts at zero

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

What I'm aiming at is systematically increase the value of `e1` from -1 to 0 in steps of 0.001. And with each value of `e1`, compute variable `uNew` with increasing values of the variable `r` by `dr` = 0.01 until `r` = 25;

But the energy keeps starting at zero instead of -1, And I can't figure out how to implement it, also, should I use two For loops?

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 1000 ; i++) {
     do {                                      
         e1 = e1 + 0.001;                  
     }while(e1 < 0 );                                                                        


      r = i*dr;
      uNew = 2*u1-u0+dr*dr*(2/r - 2*e1)*u0;            

      dr += 0.01;       
      u0 = u1;
      u1 = uNew;            
  }
```

Comment: You already have two loops - what ya talking 'bout?

Comment: It would help if you could actually write out the equation using math notation.  Then, someone can help you to translate it into Java code.

Comment: Tim is correct like this we are not able to understand your requirement

Comment: why even do the `do-while` loop, if you could just as well initialize `e1` to 0, because it will only be used as 0?

Comment: The first thing you do at each iteration of the outer for loop is to increment e1 in an inner loop until it's >= 0. Just don't. Increment it *once*.

Comment: I guess you have to put everything (the calculations) in the {do...while} block. In this way you will calculate for every "i" value all the results of energy for "e" from -1 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized the variable e1 to -1? You are just incrementing the value in do while loop. I think you need the uNew value to be calculated inside the loop.

Comment: `i` need to reach 2000 because -1 to 1 are 2000 steps. Don´t forget about this after remofing `do-while` lines.

Comment: if you want to loop from -1 to 1, you just need the do while. `e1=-1; do { e1 = e1 + 0.001; // write remaining logic} while(e1<1)`

Comment: but then you need a counter variable - because he´s calculation with `i` as step-value.

Comment: he can include counter variable in this loop itself. no need of second loop. rt?